# Undirected graph gradually remove all points but not create 2 graphs

Tags: c#, algorithm, task, undirected-graph, tarjans-algorithm

Cities are connected by telephone wires and communicating. I want destroy all cities but not alarm another too early, so i disconnect wire before destroying town. I don't want disconnect town what is used as bridge between two cities.

It is Undirected graph if I'm not mistaken. But I do not get it how i can check what cities i can remove and what not. I looked at Tarjan's Algorithm but it i don't get it.

This is test input:

```
15 19 <- Number of cities and number of connections
1 2 <- Start of connections list
2 3
2 4
2 5
5 6
5 7
7 8
8 9
5 9
1 9
10 11
1 11
11 12
12 13
13 14
1 14
9 14
13 15
9 15
```

Output can be like this:

```
10 12 6 3 14 11 4 13 15 8 9 7 5 2 1
```

Comment: I understand the problem is to remove edges (wires) and nodes (cities); it is only feasible to remove a node if it is disconnected from all other nodes. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes i think that you said it correctly. I can provide full task but it is in Czech language. only rule is to NOT remove city what is like "bridge" between two other (only if there is more ways)

Comment: Would it be a feasible strategy to select an arbitrary node, remove all edges ajacent to it and finally remove the node?

Comment: my programming skills are not good enough to even create visualise graph in program. I only see it like points and wires on paper but i dont know how to make it "programish"

Comment: @Condor No, you don't delete edges at all. The constraint is that removing a vertex must not increase a number of connected components.

Comment: Problem is solved i can send source

Answer (score 0):

I think i solved it. It just need to do DFS Algorithm. After that result what I need is reversed DFS output.

For example if DFS output is 3,5,4,1,2 result is 2,1,4,5,3

This is DFS for C#: http://www.koderdojo.com/blog/depth-first-search-algorithm-in-csharp-and-net-core